# Performing some actions and repeating them based on the time

Tags: java, android

Im writing my project app in Android Studio. The app is connected to microcontroller and send logic 1 on button Click to get data string from microcontroller all by BT. I have question for you how can i automatize it to send this logic 1 with some delay. I tried some methods but them dont work properly. The app stops

```
    //Send Button
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                sendData();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendButton.performClick();
        }
    },20000);
```

LogCat:

```
2020-03-27 18:44:10.913 11754-11754/com.example.bt_serial_test_1_0 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bt_serial_test_1_0, PID: 11754
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5645)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at com.example.bt_serial_test_1_0.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:104)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6878)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5640)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
    at com.example.bt_serial_test_1_0.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:104) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6878) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid message body
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:337)
    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:325)
    at com.example.bt_serial_test_1_0.MainActivity.sendSms(MainActivity.java:239)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5640) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
    at com.example.bt_serial_test_1_0.MainActivity$4.run(MainActivity.java:104) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6878) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

this method is in onCreate. Can someone please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: Info missing. Post all code from MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Handler example for a repeating task.

```
// Create the Handler object (on the main thread by default)
Handler handler = new Handler();
// Define the code block to be executed
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Do something here on the main thread
      Log.d("Handlers", "Called on main thread");
      // Repeat this the same runnable code block again another 2 seconds
      handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
    }
};
// Start the initial runnable task by posting through the handler
handler.post(runnableCode);
```

**You can modify it for your case like that**

```
 sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                handler().postDelayed(r,1000);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });


final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
            sendButton.performClick();
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice but it didnt worked for me. It doesnt repeat the task that i set.